# Android Nearby Connections - How to prevent overlap with connections and discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth, p2p, wifi-direct, google-nearby

I am using the Nearby Connections API. From what I've read, one should not be discovering while simultaneously being connected to a device because this reduces bandwith and causes possible dropped connections.

However, I am building an application where each phone tries to relay any message it receives to as many other phones as possible. As such, it is best to always be discovering in order to maximizing the number of endpoints.

What is the best method for ensuring that discovery time does not overlap with actual connection time? Should I be entering discovery mode on a regular preset interval? Is there a way to store discovered devices for later (so I can connect to them after I have discovering all local devices)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to discovered devices even after calling stopDiscovery, so one solution is to scan for a fixed duration, and then connect to the devices that were found. (Note: If you're trying to do something in the background, try to synchronize the devices by advertising on the start of the hour since discovery can drain a lot of battery.)

Alternatively, you can try to keep the devices continuously connected to each other, by forming 2~3 connections per device, and flooding the network by updating all of your connected peers, who then do the same, until everyone sees the message. (Note: Being connected drains battery, although not as much as discovery does)